# Python error when I try to install cloudgenix_config

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I installed Python3.9.1 and I am trying to run :
pip install cloudgenix_config or pip3 install cloudgenix_config

I keep getting the attached error:

````
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/49/b2/7c7a103c72c049ba6816f8bb29274b3ba5c0e4952c3e779f363940cad499/clo                           udgenix_config-1.0.0b2.tar.gz#sha256=5fe3101ab46cd7ca3128f914b9bee4afd0da4954f6db7b7da9de2b01380e4967 (from https://pypi.org/simpl                           e/cloudgenix-config/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached cloudgenix_config-1.0.0b1.tar.gz (57 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-z34o7ve8/cloudgenix                           -config_6817b103e5384c87b5004a215f801528/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-z34o7ve8/cloudgenix-config_6817b103e5384c87                           b5004a215f801528/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO(                           '"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code                           , __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-_ajoxfg8
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-z34o7ve8/cloudgenix-config_6817b103e5384c87b5004a215f801528/
  Complete output (11 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
      from setuptools.dist import Distribution
    File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 34, in <module>
      from setuptools import windows_support
    File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/windows_support.py", line 2, in <module>
      import ctypes
    File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
      from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e2/63/bfcf3223c5b7159779d9515dfe60381199b91cb630705b05d80be4f2d4a5/clo                           udgenix_config-1.0.0b1.tar.gz#sha256=07439d49951b8f5b9254f6098afa2bcb390109d0b30cd2fd2cfab4505b41091b (from https://pypi.org/simpl                           e/cloudgenix-config/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cloudgenix_config (from versions: 1.0.0b1, 1.0.0b2, 1.0.0b3, 1.0.0b                           4, 1.0.0b5, 1.0.0b6, 1.1.0b1, 1.2.0b1, 1.2.0b2, 1.2.0b4, 1.3.0b1, 1.3.0b2, 1.3.0b3, 1.4.0b1, 1.4.0b2, 1.4.0b4, 1.4.0b5, 1.5.0b1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cloudgenix_config```
````

Comment: Hi , I added the text in the image above. I will remove the image. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From the [PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/cloudgenix-config/), it looks like this package only supports Python 3.6 through 3.8. That is the most likely reason you're getting this kind of error. If you really need to use it, I suggest installing 3.8 if you don't already have it on your system.

Comment: One of my system that have 3.9.1 got installed on it without any error

Comment: @here any help would be appreciated